# Understanding JOINS , Sub Query and Aggregate Functions

Tags: sql, join, subquery, aggregate-functions, average

In MYSQL , I am trying to understand the Aggregate Functions and am trying some examples in the northwind schema.

The table employees has the following description.

```
    +-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id              | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | company         | varchar(50) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
    | last_name       | varchar(50) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
    | first_name      | varchar(50) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
    | email_address   | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | job_title       | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | business_phone  | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | home_phone      | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | mobile_phone    | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | fax_number      | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | address         | longtext    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | city            | varchar(50) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
    | state_province  | varchar(50) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
    | zip_postal_code | varchar(15) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
    | country_region  | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | web_page        | longtext    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | notes           | longtext    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | attachments     | longblob    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    +-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Also the data in the table is

```
    mysql> select city , first_name,last_name from employees;
    +----------+------------+----------------+
    | city     | first_name | last_name      |
    +----------+------------+----------------+
    | Seattle  | Nancy      | Freehafer      |
    | Bellevue | Andrew     | Cencini        |
    | Redmond  | Jan        | Kotas          |
    | Kirkland | Mariya     | Sergienko      |
    | Seattle  | Steven     | Thorpe         |
    | Redmond  | Michael    | Neipper        |
    | Seattle  | Robert     | Zare           |
    | Redmond  | Laura      | Giussani       |
    | Seattle  | Anne       | Hellung-Larsen |
    +----------+------------+----------------+
```

I am trying to understand how can I find the Average number of people from different cities.

Till Now , I have

```
    mysql> select city,count(city) from employees group by city;
    +----------+-------------+
    | city     | count(city) |
    +----------+-------------+
    | Bellevue |           1 |
    | Kirkland |           1 |
    | Redmond  |           3 |
    | Seattle  |           4 |
    +----------+-------------+
```

Also I have

```
    SELECT SUM(inner_count_city) from 
    (
            SELECT   city  AS  inner_city, 
            COUNT(*)   AS inner_count_city
            FROM  employees
            GROUP BY inner_city
    ) temp_table;
    +-----------------------+
    | SUM(inner_count_city) |
    +-----------------------+
    |                     9 |
    +-----------------------+
```

I am struggling to proceed forward do this due to the following reasons.

- I am not able to do a AVG(COUNT(city)) - cant do two aggregate function
- I am also not sure , how to divide it by the sum of count of cities ( = 9).
- Not sure if I should use unions or joins , or subqueries.

I am trying to do something like

- select city , inner_count_city / sum (inner_count_city) from ..

Comment: What DBMS are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL only supports one aggregation at a time; for multiple aggregations you need multiple subqueries/CTEs.  If you want the *average* number of people in the cities, then you are almost there:

```
SELECT AVG(inner_count_city * 1.0) from 
FROM (SELECT   city  AS  inner_city, COUNT(*) AS inner_count_city
      FROM  employees
      GROUP BY inner_city
     ) c;
```

Note that SQL Server does integer arithmetic on integers.  So the average of 1 and 2 is 1, not 1.5.  Hence the `* 1.0`.

You can do this without a subquery as well:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) * 1.0 / COUNT(DISTINCT city)
FROM employees;
```

Comment: Thanks , But what if I was looking , for what percentage of people are coming from each different city.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `AVG` aggregate function in an outer query:

```
select avg(cnt)
FROM (select count(city) as cnt 
      from employees 
      group by city) as t
```

To get the percentage of people per city you can use the following query:

```
select city, count(city) * 100.0 / total_count as cnt 
from employees 
cross join (select count(*) as total_count from employees) AS t
group by city, total_count
```

Comment: Thanks , But what if I was looking , for what percentage of people are coming from each different city.

Comment: Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 't.total_count' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Thanks , works like a charm , Can you elaborate why cross join.

Comment: I ask because I see that even JOIN works instead of cross join.

Comment: @user2977259 `CROSS JOIN` is generally the preferred method to join a scalar value like in this case.